# SimplifySwift recursion issues with certain data sets

Tags: swift, macos, recursion

I am using the SimplifySwift library by tomislav in a MacOS application which uses a recursive function to reduce the number of data points along a line. It works great for me under most conditions, however I have recently discovered that certain data sets cause a stack overflow with the recursion. Based on the data causing the issue, my guess is that when it is a large data set with very few or no points that can be removed it eventually hits the stack limit. The case that causes the crash is a series of points that only alternate between 0% and 100%, leaving nothing that can be reduced. This is a valid data set in my application, and I don't know how I could distinguish something like it from any other data set in advance in order to know not to run it through the simplifier. It would be helpful if anyone could suggest either a way to improve the recursion on these functions, or help me identify the exact issue more specifically so that I could somehow check the data before entering the crashing situation.

**Update:** Based on a suggestion in the comments I have now been able to make this work with the problem data set by using a custom Thread with an increased stack size instead of GCD. However, this feels like a bit of a band aid solution since the custom stack size I'm using (2mb) is an arbitrary value that works in this case, but I assume theoretically could still have the same problem with a different, larger data set. I would like to keep this open for now to see if anyone has any thoughts on a way to detect a problematic data set at runtime, or a way of implementing these functions that doesn't create such a heavy stack load.

These are the functions that lead to the eventual overflow:

```
fileprivate class func simplifyDouglasPeucker<T:SimplifyValue>(
    _ points: [T],
    tolerance: Float!
) -> [T] {
    if points.count <= 2 {
        return points
    }
    
    let lastPoint: Int = points.count - 1
    var result: [T] = [points.first!]
    simplifyDouglasPeuckerStep(points, first: 0, last: lastPoint, tolerance: tolerance, simplified: &result)
    result.append(points[lastPoint])
    return result
}

fileprivate class func simplifyDouglasPeuckerStep<T:SimplifyValue>(
    _ points: [T],
    first: Int,
    last: Int,
    tolerance: Float,
    simplified: inout [T]
) {
    var maxSquareDistance = tolerance
    var index = 0
    
    for i in first + 1 ..< last {
        let sqDist = getSquareSegmentDistance(point: points[i], seg1: points[first], seg2: points[last])
        if sqDist > maxSquareDistance {
            index = i
            maxSquareDistance = sqDist
        }
    }
    
    if maxSquareDistance > tolerance {
        if index - first > 1 {
            simplifyDouglasPeuckerStep(points, first: first, last: index, tolerance: tolerance, simplified: &simplified)
        }
        simplified.append(points[index])
        if last - index > 1 {
            simplifyDouglasPeuckerStep(points, first: index, last: last, tolerance: tolerance, simplified: &simplified)
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the first few points of the array of CGPoint that I am having trouble with. Should be enough to show the pattern of the data that is replicated through the entire array:

```
Simplifying 2143 points in pointsArray: [(0.0, 0.0), (6359.0, 0.0), (6360.0, 100.0), (6392.0, 100.0), (6393.0, 0.0), (6425.0, 0.0), (6426.0, 100.0), (6458.0, 100.0), (6459.0, 0.0), (6492.0, 0.0), (6493.0, 100.0), (6525.0, 100.0), (6526.0, 0.0), (6558.0, 0.0), (6559.0, 100.0), (6592.0, 100.0), (6593.0, 0.0), (6625.0, 0.0), (6626.0, 100.0), (6658.0, 100.0), (6659.0, 0.0), (6692.0, 0.0), (6693.0, 100.0), (6725.0, 100.0), (6726.0, 0.0), (6758.0, 0.0), (6759.0, 100.0), (6792.0, 100.0), (6793.0, 0.0), (6825.0, 0.0), (6826.0, 100.0), (6858.0, 100.0)...
```

EDIT: I don't know if it's helpful or not, but thought I should add that this function with the exact same data set works fine when run on the main thread (but with the expected few seconds of beachball action). I assume this is due to the main thread stack size being larger. When run on a background thread it always crashes at the same point with 905 items on the stack.

Comment: It's not clear to me if this problem even needs recursion. It just looks like a really complicated way to do a `map` or `filter` (I don't quite understand this code; and that's oftne the problem with recursion lol)

Comment: See [Consistent crash when allocating large memory in DispatchQueue](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/111128)

Comment: @Willeke thanks for the link. It led me to creating my own thread with a custom stack size instead of using GCD, which allows it to finish with my problematic data set. I noted this in an update, but leaving this open for now because I'd like to see if anyone has any thoughts on a solution that actually detects or resolves the problem instead of just dumping an arbitrary amount of additional resources on it.

Comment: Could you give us a sample input and the expected result? This looks like a really trivial map/filter problem that doesn’t need any recursion at all. I can take a stab at later

Comment: @Alexander I could be wrong as I'm definitely not a mathematician, but I don't believe this is as simple as just a map/filter. It's using multiple algorithms to take a series of points along a graphed line and determine which points can be removed while retaining the visual appearance of the plot. An extremely basic input example would be points on a straight line, like [(0,5), (1,5), (2,5)...(20,5)]. This set could be reduced to just [(0,5), (20,5)] without changing the visual appearance of the line. But it gets far more complicated when the plotted curve is NOT a straight line.

Comment: The full library I'm using is [here](https://github.com/tomislav/Simplify-Swift)

Comment: Google found [Iterative version of Ramer-Douglas-Peucker line-simplification algorithm](https://namekdev.net/2014/06/iterative-version-of-ramer-douglas-peucker-line-simplification-algorithm/).

Comment: @Willeke that seems promising, I just have to convert it over to Swift. Thanks! Feel free to add as a solution if you want.